# The use of “So X as to [be] Y”

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, expressions, syntactic-analysis

First of all, note that this is not a duplicate question of another one asking about the usage of *so as to*, since this one is asking about the structure of *so . . . as to. . . .*

I understand this might have been a better question at the [English Language Learners site](http://ell.stackexchange.com), since I’m not a native English speaker. I am asking it here since I want to get some professional advice in regard to this question, since I don’t seem to have found anything similar to this on the Internet.

At the Oxford Dictionaries Online (OD) I have found the following definition of *ludicrous*:

> So foolish, unreasonable, or out of place as to be amusing.

I understand the phrase *so as to*, simply meaning *in order to* and preceding the purpose for which an action is done.

*So* by itself is just *therefore*, *hence*, *thus*, or a way of emphasizing an adjective or adverb.

*As to* in itself means *with regard to* or *according to*, as pointed out in [the Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/as+to).

In the OD definition of *ludicrous*, the use of *so* looks fair to me, that is, it clearly emphasizes the high extent to which something is foolish or unreasonable.

The use of *as to* doesn’t work in any way I’ve mentioned in this case (neither as in *with regard to* nor *according to*). I think the dictionary I’ve referred to has missed one, if not more, meaning of the phrase *as to*.

In this case, it appears to have likely been used as an alternative to *that* when used in the form *So X, that Y*, meaning something is or happens X (a combination of adjectives or adverbs) enough to cause Y to happen.

Of course, I don’t mean that in the structure *so X as to Y* the phrase *as to* is absolutely equivalent to *that*, since substituting *as to* with *that* changes the structure of Y.

Does all this mean that the phrase *as to* is a great alternative to *that* (although changing the structure of Y) whenever the sentence is of the form *so X, that Y* (where X is a combination of one or more adjectives or adverbs)?

I am new here and so I’m not too familiar with the variety of existing tags here, so if anyone sees an additional one that would fit, please add it to this question. I would also be glad to see some other corrections of my grammar.

Comment: I can't follow all of your thinking here, but you seem to have gone astray early on where you set out your understanding of ***so*** in constructions like *so X as to be Y*, where it actually means [*to such a great extent*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/so) (the first definition in that link).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, substitute the phrase 'as to' with 'with regard to' or 'according to' (the only definitions of 'as to' found on the site provided in the question), and the sentence loses its meaning. That means that 'as to' has some other meanings that aren't anything like the ones listed on the website I've linked to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree I may not have been too clear about what I do not understand. I have seen a lot of questions/explanations regarding 'So ..., that ...', but none that would ask about/explain 'So... as to be ...', which seems to look similar in meaning.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as that. The thing is you're assuming **as to** has some special meaning *as a consecutive pair of words*. But this approach will come unstuck if you also assume **as** on its own also has a special meaning, and that **as to be** has yet another one. The **as to** in *so confident as to answer* doesn't mean "with regard to". You have to recognise that these little words have many different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But it _does_ mean that the dictionary I've linked to has missed a definition that would accordingly fit in some context and which would be the only one that could explain the meaning of 'as to' in that context.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that at all. It just so happens that **as to = regarding** is an idiomatic term that some dictionaries will list separately because it's not obvious whether it should be listed under **as** or **to**. But *so X as to Y* would more likely be included under the entry for **so** (in which context it has no real connection to the two-word idiom). You can see that by noting my earlier comment where I said *"I wouldn't go so far **as** that"* (where there is no **to** anyway).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now I'm wondering whether the other definition of 'so' shown on OD is the one that is used in the definition of 'ludicrous', namely the second one: 'to the same extent (used in comparisons)', which sounds identical to one of the definitions of 'as'. Does that mean that the sentence 'As foolish, unreasonable, or out of place as to be amusing.' is identical to 'So foolish, unreasonable, or out of place as to be amusing.'?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Additionally, I thought that 'so...as...' can only used in negative context, which does not exist in 'So foolish, unreasonable, or out of place as to be amusing.'. I'm confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15337/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-mathh).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have nevertheless posted a similar question on ELL SE that may clarify what I mean and get some opinions of the people hanging out on ELL SE (some of them may not be using the EL&U SE too much). I am sorry if this is not exactly an appropriate course of action.

Comment: In case you didn't know, you can include links in comments by putting [some text like this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26942/) in [square] brackets, immediately followed by a URL web address in (round) brackets. With any luck some of the ELU users who should be on ELL in the first place might follow the link and discover a site more suitable to their needs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. I was not aware of the way of using this option in comments (when asking a question/answering a question, there is a clear '_Hyperlink_' button, which is not implemented in the comment sections).

Comment: It's very handy if you want to post "smartass" comments. Particularly on ELL - where if you allude to some common saying, for example, in a comment primarily directed at another user you assume **will** "get" the reference, it's a courtesy to include a link to the reference so others can maybe share the joke.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The problem with trying to bracket ***as to*** with ***so*** is that it is used with exactly the same type of resultative meaning with words like ***enough***. For example: ***... big enough as to necessitate ...***

Comment: Great question! I think your intuitions are all correct. I'm going to have a go at answering this in a sec (may take me a while to do though ... )

Comment: @Araucaria: I think "the problem" is actually that OP seeks to understand the use of prepositions and other "glue" words by consulting dictionary definitions (of single words, or idiomatically common collocations). These things are probably better understood by consulting *grammar* books.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you think ***as*** is a preposition here?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I kind of agree with your last comment, bu I don't think this one will be easy to sort out from a normal grammar reference - if any at all ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *So* foolish, unreasonable, or out of place *as to* be amusing.

Here are some more examples of this construction. This time in full sentences:

- This action was so forceful/beautiful/thoughtless/terrifying as to cause the audience to burst into tears.
- She sang so beautifully/movingly as to cause her audience to take to the aisles.

We’ll revisit these sentences below. Before we dive in, however, a brief diversion:

### *A diversion*

Some words, rather than having a meaning of the sort you can look up in a dictionary, can only be interpreted from the context in which they occur. This might be the physical environment or the actual conversation that they occur in. In order to interpret them you often need to orientate yourself to the position of the speaker or intended listener.

Examples of this are the words *I* and *you*. To illustrate, *I* at the moment of speaking, as you read this, refers to 'Araucaria'. You know this because you understand that the word *I* points towards the person who is speaking (or writing) in order to show who it is meant to refer to. Generally speaking the word *I* does not mean *Araucaria*

Another word like this is *today*. At the point of writing, *today* refers to 26th of June 2014 (British Summer Time). If you look up *today* in a dictionary, it won't say "26th June ... ." To understand *today* you orientate yourself to the position of the speaker at the time of speaking. You understand that the day that they intend to refer to, is the day during which they are, or were, speaking.

The term for this kind of linguistic pointing is *deixis*.  *I* and *you*, *this* and *that*, *yesterday* and *tomorrow* are deictic words.  *That* is a useful word to consider at this point. An important point here is that in order to understand *that*, we need some form of contextual clue to grasp what the speaker is referring to. We might get the clue from the rest of the conversation - or we might get it from the physical environment we are in.

For example, someone might say *Give me that* whilst pointing at a banana. We understand that the speaker is using the word *that* to represent a certain banana. However, we don't understand this from the conversation itself but through the speaker physically pointing towards the intended referent. If the speaker was standing in a greengrocer's we wouldn't understand what they were referring to if they did not point! Deictic words like *that* require that some kind of clue is given to facilitate their interpretation.

### *So (x)*

Back then to *so ... as to*.  In the definition in question, *so* is a deictic adverb. It is also a degree adverb; it points to the size, extent, measure or degree of a property. This property usually appears in the sentence in the guise of an adjective:

- This action was so forceful/beautiful/thoughtless/terrifying as to cause the audience to burst into tears.

In the example above *so* is syntactically and semantically modifying the adjective that comes after it. However, as with other adverbs of degree such a *quite*, *rather* and *extremely*, *so* also commonly modifies adverbs:

- She danced so forcefully/beautifully as to cause the audience to ...

As mentioned above *so* refers to the extent of the property described in the word it is syntactically modifying. Crucially, in a normal sentence ( - not an exclamation) the speaker must indicate how big or small this is. They must provide some kind of index which explains how great this extent actually is. In the same way as previously discussed with *that*, this information may come from the environment that the speaker or listener finds themselves in, or it might come from the text of the conversation itself.

A fisherman, for example, telling his friends about a fish that got away, may hold his hands apart in front of him and say:

- "It was about so big, and it had...,

Or someone wanting to indicate how tall a particular plant is  may hold their hand out above the ground and say:

- "It's about so tall ...

Which may shortly be followed by:

- ... and about so wide."

Here the index is provided physically by the speaker’s hands.

When no such environmental clue is given, the exact measure or degree that the word *so* represents must be provided in the conversation itself. In the construction we are talking about, this extent is explicitly explained in the phrase beginning with *as to...*. Consider the following example:

- His ears were so big as to block out the sun.

Here the phrase *to block out the sun* doesn't only tell us a potential result of the ear situation. The result itself, as described in the phrase, fulfils the linguistic function of providing the required index for the 'extent' of the bigness. In other words, it has the function of informing us of the 'extent' represented by the adverb *so*. This, as we have described, is a mandatory feature of the use of this word in non-exclamations.

### *As* ...

The preposition *as* often appears in comparative structures concerning equality:

- as heavy as an elephant.
- (not) such a heavy animal as  an elephant.
- (not) so heavy as an elephant.

In the first example, you may notice that there are two forms of ‘as’. The first is a degree adverb modifying the adjective *heavy*. The second, which we are currently concerned with, is the preposition. This particular *as* normally introduces something which is being equalled (or surpassed) in some way by another item in the sentence. So in the sentence:

- Bob is as tall as Bertha.

… *Bertha* represents an entity whose ‘tallness’ is at least equalled and maybe surpassed by Bob. In all these constructions the *as* phrase has an indexing function where it sets some kind of benchmark which is met (or, where negation is involved, not met).

In the ***so (x) as to (y)*** construction, this benchmark indicates the intensity of the degree adverb *so*.  It tells us that the ‘extent’ of the x-ness meets or exceeds the level required to cause ‘y’ to occur.

*As*, like other prepositions, can take different complements. When used with this indexing function, *as* often takes a clause in which material - echoing sections from the superordinate clause - has been deleted:

- Bob is as tall as *Bertha (is tall).*
- was not so heavy as *an elephant (is heavy).*
- The second party was not such a success as *the first (party was a
  success).*

However, in the ***so (x) as to (y)*** construction, there is no repetition of this type of material from the main clause, whether it is deleted or not. Here a finite clause is not possible with the same meaning:

- She danced so beautifully as that the audience clapped.  * (wrong)

The clause after *as* must be a non-finite infinitival clause. In the examples given these all begin with the word *to*. It would be tempting to think that the *to* here actually belongs to some kind of *as to* phrase. It does not!

### *To*

There is simple evidence from negative clauses that shows that *to* belongs with the following verb phrase, not with *as*:

- so small as [not to be seen distinctly without a magnifying glass].

The word *not* here precedes *to*. It is the entire verb phrase following *not* which has been negated.

Further note that there is a missing subject in all ***so (x) as to (y)*** clauses:

- The music was so awful as to cause the revellers to stand still.

Here the subject of the verb *CAUSE* is understood to be the music. In such sentences, the subject of the subordinate clause is always understood as being the same as the subject in the main clause:

- The music was so awful as (for the music) to cause the revellers to stand still.
- It was so foolish, unreasonable, and out of place as (for it) to be amusing.

If we wish to introduce a completely different subject, it is necessary for it to be introduced by the subordinator *for* (a relatively rare occurrence):

- It was not so serious as for the government to take any action.

Here the subject of the main clause is *it*, which may refer to a specific situation. We have a different subject for the infinitival clause, *the government*, and this clause is therefore mandatorily preceded by *for*. This demonstrates again that *to* in this construction is part of the verb phrase, it is not part of an idiomatic *as to* phrase.

### '*so (x) as to (y)*' and '*so (x) that (y)*'

The Original Poster noted that  ***so (x) as to (y)*** and ***so (x) that (y)*** constructions are similar. They are, but they are certainly not the same. There are important semantic and grammatical differences. First, however, let us consider the similarities. Firstly, the function of the *as* and  *that*  clauses are the same. They both provide an index for the interpretation of the adverb *so*. Secondly, the clauses both describe some kind of result.

However, as the OP also noted, the grammar of the two constructions is different. Here is how it’s different: firstly, *as* in the first construction is obligatory, *that* in the second is not:

- so foolish as to be amusing.
- so foolish to be amusing. * (wrong)
- so foolish that it is amusing.
- so foolish it is amusing.

This mirrors the fact that *as* in the first construction is a preposition and heads the phrase. *That* in the second is a subordinator and merely marks the phrase that follows as subordinate. Moreover, the verb in the *as* construction, as we noted, is non-finite. It has no tensed verb. Instead it uses an infinitive. The clause cannot stand on its own:

- To cause her to burst into tears. (not a full sentence).

The clause marked by *that* on the other hand is a finite clause with a verb that has tense. The clause can stand as a sentence in its own right:

- It is amusing.

Lastly, we previously noted that the subject in the *as* phrase is omitted in a ***so (x) as to (y)*** sentence. The subject in the clause with *that* contrastingly must be overtly stated:

- It was so foolish as to be amusing.
- It was so foolish that *it* was amusing.
- It was so foolish that was amusing. * (wrong)

So much for the grammar. The OP also wondered about the semantics of *as* and *that*. Well, *as*, as discussed above introduces some kind of benchmark which is met or exceeded. *That* appears to have no meaning at all -  a point reinforced by the fact that we can miss it out altogether without it affecting the meaning of the sentence. More fundamentally important however, is that the two constructions do not mean the same thing. They do not have the same truth values. Consider the sentence below:

- My pet cobra had a venom so powerful as for its bite to kill a grown adult in less than thirty seconds.

Because the verb in the subordinate clause is an infinitive, it gives a theoretical meaning to the proposition it introduces. The proposition may or may not have actually occurred. The result shown, which is of an adult dying from the venom within thirty seconds of being bitten, is hypothetical, not factual in the sense of describing a real individual who died. In the construction with *that* the verb is tensed. This usually encodes that the sentence be considered as a factual state of affairs, not a hypothetical one. Compare the example above with the following:

- My pet cobra had a venom so powerful that its bite killed a grown adult in less than thirty seconds.

This sentence is rather more alarming than the first, because it involves a factual, not notional fatality.  The ***so (x) as to (y)*** construction implies a notional result, the ***so (x) that (y)*** sentence on the other hand entails a factual result.

### Conclusion

In ***so … as to*** sentences, *so* is a deictic adverb of degree. *So* receives its interpretation from its intensity being indexed by a notional result (which may or may not be interpreted as having actually happened). This result is described in a non-finite clause headed by the preposition *as*. Where *to* follows the preposition, the subject of the clause is omitted, and is interpreted as being identical to the subject of the main clause. The *to* in this construction is part of an infinitival verb phrase, it is not part of an *as to* idiom, or an *as to* subordinator. Although ***so … as to*** sentences bear certain similarities to ***so … that*** sentences, they are materially different constructions, both in terms of meaning and form.

Comment: Thanks!! All this must've taken quite some time, I appreciate it.

Comment: @mathh My pleasure, a surprisingly interesting and complex question. Thanks!

Comment: That was an ANSWER! Thank you! There's some issue with another question which I'm dealing with and it's also related to the current question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/250208/so-as-vs-so-that . Do you have any Ideas about it? -Thanks... @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.

Answer (score 2):

The word *so* is an adverb that means, in this context, *to such a great extent*. For instance, you might say:

> He was driving **so** fast that he lost control of the car.

This is the sense that applies in the sentence you quote. The phrase *as to be* is simply another way to say *that it is*. So your sentence is saying that someone is very foolish, to such a great degree that it is amusing.

This use of *so* is mostly unrelated to its use as a conjunction that means *therefore*.