# as to + infinitive

Tags: phrases, expressions

hii I was wondering if this sentence was correct "... they could feel threatened by them, feeling that technology will one day be so advanced as to replace them entirely."

^_^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The use of “So X as to {be} Y”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180776/the-use-of-so-x-as-to-be-y)

Comment: The answer at Edwin Ashworth's link (by _Araucaria - Not here any more_) is wonderfully  clear. Please look no further! I've found several discussions of **so … as to** elsewhere, but they all lead to confusion.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. The preposition phrase "as to replace them entirely" is licenced by the "so" that modifies "advanced". You could also have "... technology will one day be so advanced that it will replace them entirely" with no change of meaning, where the declarative content (_that_) clause is also licensed by "so".